# using rxjs map function gives error property _isScalar missing

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and typescript, tring to learn it with [this tutorial](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/meteor/chats-page). There's a handler in the tutorial that looks like this:

```
removeChat(chat: Chat): void {
    this.chats = this.chats.map<Chat[]>(chatsArray => {
        const chatIndex = chatsArray.indexOf(chat);
        chatsArray.splice(chatIndex, 1);

        return chatsArray;
    });
}
```

However, the tutorial is somewhat outdated, since it thinks `of` and `map` are methods of Observable, when it is no longer the case. So I tried fixing it by importing them separately. `of` worked well (it's used to fetch mock data and set it to this.chats). `map` is giving me issues, probably because I'm not understanding the syntax well enough (I'm very well versed in Javascript, but typescript is still very new to me). So I tried something like this

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// later...
removeChat(chat: Chat): void {
    this.chats = map<Chat[], {}>(chatsArray => {
        const chatIndex = chatsArray.indexOf(chat);
        chatsArray.splice(chatIndex, 1);

        return chatsArray;
    });
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Type 'OperatorFunction' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.   Property '_isScalar' is missing in type
>   'OperatorFunction'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, it doesn't know which `Observable` it should be operating on. Instead, you should use it in conjunction with `pipe`, like so:

```
  removeChat(chat: Chat): void {
    this.chats = this.chats.pipe(
      map(chatsArray => {
        const chatIndex = chatsArray.indexOf(chat);
        chatsArray.splice(chatIndex, 1);

        return chatsArray;
      }));
  }
```